# Looking for a seed project mixing Angular2 (>= rc5, i.e. vith ngModule) AND AngularFire2

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angularfire2

I think we could do great things by using Firebase within Angular2. In this case, Firebase is used as an "extension" to **Angular2** and is thus named **AngularFire2**.
But, at  this time, I cannot find a seed project of AngularFire2 with an **Angular2 version greater or equal to RC5**, id est using *module* concept : app.module.ts,  `@ngModule`, etc.
**1.** Has anyone found such a HelloWorld?

Moreover, if **Angular CLI** could help us buying such a project, that would be perfect. But from what I read, it can still not generate an Angular 2 project with the *module* concept.
**2.** If anyone has details about this, welcome !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to run a Angular2 app w/ AngularFire2.
I followed steps described in https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/1-install-and-setup.md.

Concerning Angular CLI, I have installed Angular CLI 1.0.0-beta.15. Of course, it deals with *modules* of Angular2.

Concerning Angularfire2 installation in my project, I got a lot of red **Cannot find namespace 'firebase'** after typing `ng serve`.
I solved this by adding `/// <reference path="../firebase/firebase.d.ts" />` at the beginning of `PROJECT_DIRECTORY/node_modules/angularfire2/angularfire2.d.ts`. If I'm not wrong, it allows Angularfire2 to access Firebase types definition file.
I found this solution here : https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/525

Answer (score 0):

I setup a project few days back, it works for me.

https://github.com/balajicuttackam/angularfire2-seed

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Balaji. I'll test and tell you.

Comment: I have installed Angular CLI 1.0.0-beta.15.